# How to get absolutepath of a uploaded file in Yii

Tags: php, yii

In my application am trying to get the absolute path(example - e:\Server\MyFile\home.txt) of uploaded file. I have tried getName() method. But still it shows that home.txt. Just i would like to know how to get full path? Please give me an idea. Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code which is in my controller.

```
$csvFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file'); 
$tempLoc=$csvFile->getName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$csvFile->getTempName()` to get the path and name of the temporary file created.